# Do i need to install Nvidia's SDK(CUDA) for OpenCL to detect Nvidia GPU?

Tags: c, linux, cuda, parallel-processing, opencl

I have a code written in C (using opencl specs) to list all the available devices. My PC has an AMD FirePro as well as Nvidia's Tesla graphics card installed. I first installed [AMD-APP-SDK-v3.0-0.113.50-Beta-linux64.tar.bz2](http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/opencl-zone/amd-accelerated-parallel-processing-app-sdk/#) but it didn't seem to work so thereafter I installed OpenCL™ Runtime 15.1 for Intel® Core™ and Intel® Xeon® Processors for Red Hat* and SLES* Linux* OS (64-bit) & then [OpenCL™ Code Builder](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/opencl-drivers#sdk) .
But the following code lists only the CPU and does not detect the 2 graphics card.

```
int main() {
int i, j;
char* value;
size_t valueSize;
cl_uint platformCount;
cl_platform_id* platforms;
cl_uint deviceCount;
cl_device_id* devices;
cl_uint maxComputeUnits;
cl_device_type* dev_type;

// get all platforms
clGetPlatformIDs(2, NULL, &platformCount);
platforms = (cl_platform_id*) malloc(sizeof(cl_platform_id) * platformCount);
clGetPlatformIDs(platformCount, platforms, NULL);

for (i = 0; i < platformCount; i++) {

    // get all devices
    clGetDeviceIDs(platforms[i], CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, 0, NULL, &deviceCount);
    devices = (cl_device_id*) malloc(sizeof(cl_device_id) * deviceCount);
    clGetDeviceIDs(platforms[i], CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ALL, deviceCount, devices, NULL);



clGetPlatformInfo(platforms[i], CL_PLATFORM_NAME, 0, NULL, &valueSize);
        value = (char*) malloc(valueSize);
        clGetPlatformInfo(platforms[i], CL_PLATFORM_NAME, valueSize, value, NULL);
        printf("\n%d. Platform: %sn", j+1, value);
        free(value);

    // for each device print critical attributes
    for (j = 0; j < deviceCount; j++) {

        // print device name
        clGetDeviceInfo(devices[j], CL_DEVICE_NAME, 0, NULL, &valueSize);
        value = (char*) malloc(valueSize);
        clGetDeviceInfo(devices[j], CL_DEVICE_NAME, valueSize, value, NULL);
        printf("\n%d.%d Device: %sn", j+1,1, value);
        free(value);

        // print hardware device version
        clGetDeviceInfo(devices[j], CL_DEVICE_TYPE, 0, NULL, &valueSize);
        dev_type = (cl_device_type*) malloc(valueSize);
        clGetDeviceInfo(devices[j], CL_DEVICE_TYPE, valueSize, dev_type, NULL);
        if(*dev_type==CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU)
        printf("\nIts a CPU.");
        if(*dev_type==CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU)
        printf("\nIts a GPU.");
        if(*dev_type==CL_DEVICE_TYPE_ACCELERATOR)
        printf("\nIts a ACCELERATOR.");

        free(dev_type);

        // print software driver version
        clGetDeviceInfo(devices[j], CL_DRIVER_VERSION, 0, NULL, &valueSize);
        value = (char*) malloc(valueSize);
        clGetDeviceInfo(devices[j], CL_DRIVER_VERSION, valueSize, value, NULL);
        printf(" \n%d.%d Software version: %sn", j+1, 2, value);
        free(value);


        // print parallel compute units
        clGetDeviceInfo(devices[j], CL_DEVICE_MAX_COMPUTE_UNITS,
                sizeof(maxComputeUnits), &maxComputeUnits, NULL);
        printf(" \n%d.%d Parallel compute units: %dn\n", j+1, 4, maxComputeUnits);

    }

    free(devices);

}

free(platforms);
return 0;}
```

This is what it returns:

```
gcc -lOpenCL 1.c -o 1 && ./1
1. Platform: AMD Accelerated Parallel Processingn
1.1 Device: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X5660  @ 2.80GHzn
Its a CPU. 
1.2 Software version: 1642.5 (sse2)n 
1.4 Parallel compute units: 24n
```

Do I need to install any other driver or is there anything wrong with the code?

Comment: No, you do *not* need the SDK. You need to install their driver, which will come with the OpenCL libraries and provide ICD support. The same is true for AMD GPUs - you will need their driver (`fglrx`). Installing both drivers simultaneously might be tricky though.

Comment: clinfo gives this:  Number of platforms: 1
  Platform Version: OpenCL 2.0 AMD-APP (1642.5)
  Platform Name: AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing
  Platform Extensions: cl_khr_icd cl_amd_event_callback cl_amd_offline_devices 


  Platform Name: AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing
Number of devices:  1
  Device Type: CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU
  Platform ID: 0x7fc6343ad830
  Name:Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           X5660  @ 2.80GHz
  Vendor: GenuineIntel
  Device OpenCL C version:OpenCL C 1.2 
  Driver version: 1642.5 (sse2)
  Profile: FULL_PROFILE
  Version: OpenCL 1.2 AMD-APP (1642.5)

Comment: Run `dmesg | grep fglrx | grep module` to see if something comes up. If not then you didn't installed AMD graphics driver. Also for the first time you may need to run your opencl program with `sudo` so that everything initializes in the system. Also you may need to stop your desktop GUI too.

Comment: Its an Nvidia Tesla graphics card. Please suggest a specific driver that I should install to fix the issue. OS is RHEL

Comment: Install latest [CUDA](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads), there is driver too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only thing that should be required for an NVIDIA GPU to support OpenCL is the GPU driver.  The CUDA toolkit should not be necessary.

An appropriate NVIDIA GPU driver for your GPU and OS can be found using the wizard [here](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us).

Comment: Already installed the drivers. But the thing is when I run the code in root domain, it lists the GPUs while for any other user (with limited privilages) it shows only the CPU.

Comment: We can at least agree now that the driver is sufficient (at least for root). The root vs. non-root problem is a different one than what you describe in your question.  The NVIDIA GPU needs to have certain device files created before they can be usable (for any purpose).  These files must be created by a privileged user (root, or X via the kernel.)  Once created, the GPU should be usable by any user (assuming those files have permissions set correctly.)